# Как писать именно так

Tags: javascript

Встречал неоднократно данную конструкцию, дословно не помню, но что та вроде этого

```
item.(onmouseenter = e => {
                        
}).onmouseleave = () => { }
```

Не работает, но похоже, суть в том, чтобы вешать 2 и более события на одну переменную, то есть не так писать как ниже

```
item.onmouseenter = e => {};
item.onmouseleave = () => {}
```

Это круто, удобно, но что та не выходит выполнить, подскажите как подобное возможно реализовывать?

Comment: в нативном js нет такого

Comment: Можно пример, как это реализуется, функция, за счет чего, как?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43695141/6104996    или с помощью jquery

Comment: если не хочется писать две строки, можно писать 3: [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)